# Check the Continuity and differentiability of function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Given the function $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} . \sin\left (\frac{y^2}{x}  \right ) & \text{ if } x \neq 0 \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x= 0
\end{cases}$$

I have to check the continuity and differentiability of function at $(0,0)$

**Solution I tried**
I used the sufficient condition for continuity

> *A sufficient condition that a function f be continuous at (a,b) is that one of the partial derivatives exists and is bounded in a neighbourhood of (a,b) and other exists at that point*

so i find the $f_x$ and $f_y$ at point $(0,0)$ and they both are zero ,so  **function is continuous** at $(0,0)$

for differentiability i tried $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{||f(x,y)-xf_x(0,0)-yf_y(0,0)-f(0,0)||}{||(x,y)||}$$

i got $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} || \sin\left (\frac{y^2}{x}  \right ) ||}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} || \sin\left (\frac{y^2}{x}  \right ) ||$$

next if i take polar cordinate $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$

$$\lim_{r \to 0} || \sin\left (\frac{r \sin^2 \theta}{ \cos \theta}  \right ) || \to 0$$

it goes to zero  , so the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$

but i am not confirmed about last calculation , please help me to check this solution

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The statement

$$\lim\limits_{r \to 0} \sin \left(r\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos \theta}\right)=0$$ is correct for $\theta$ fixed.

Unfortunately, this is not sufficient to evaluate the limit at the origin.

As you noticed, **if the derivative** would exist at the origin,  it would be the always vanishing linear map.

But $$\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{f(y^2, y)}{\sqrt{y^4+y^2}}= \sin 1 \neq 0$$ proving that $f$ is not differentiable at the origin.

The continuity at the origin is clear as

$$\vert f(x,y)\vert \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I am not getting the line "if the derivative would exist at the origin, it would be the always vanishing linear map" can you please elaborate this?

Comment: This is the consequence of the fact that both partial derivatives vanish at the origin.